# Wordpress - Get Categories with download manager

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `download manager` to protect some post files.

So I create a category `Download Files` and a child `Private Stuff`.

Now I create a custom template and I want load all categories inside Download Files but I can't do this and I don't understand why because I do this usually with wordpress.

**Get Categories**
    //119 is Parent category download manager ID
    $category = 119;

```
    $args = array(
                                'category' => $category,
                                'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );


    $argsChild = array('child_of' => $category);
    $childCategories = get_categories( $argsChild );

    $downloads = get_posts($args);
```

But it returns me all posts and no categories.

How can I list categories from Download Manager and list all posts from Download Manager. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

By download manager, if you meant https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/, the plugin using custom post type for downloads and custom taxonomy as category. The taxonomy name is `wpdmcategory`. So, you need to use `'post_type' => 'wpdmpro'` and `tax_query` parameter there like this:

```
$args = array(
         'post_type' => 'wpdmpro',
         'tax_query' => array(
                'taxonomy' => 'wpdmcategory',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $category,                         
          ),
         'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );
$downloads = get_posts($args);
$childCategories = get_terms("wpdmcategory", array('parent' => $category));
```